# If $(u, v)\in W^{1, p}(\Omega)\times W^{1, q}(\Omega)$, what does the notation $|(u, v)|$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain, $p, q>1$ and let $W= W^{1, p}(\Omega)\times W^{1, q}(\Omega)$. Let $(u, v)\in W$.

What does the notation $|(u, v)|$ mean?

It is in my math class notes, but. I don't understand it. Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Most likely $|(\cdot,\cdot)|$ denotes the $L^2$-inner product.

Comment: IMHO also $(u,v) = \int_\Omega \nabla u(x)^\top \nabla v(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ might be possible, but less likely than $(u,v) = \int_\Omega u(x) v(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.